# How can I invoke Chrome's built-in xml parser using Angular 6?

Tags: xml, angular, xslt

We have a set of XML documents on the cloud that we want to serve using Angular. We have an XSL file with the needed transform for all the XML documents. (The documents are all in the same format.) Ideally, we would want to maximize the work on the client side (CPU cycles on the cloud cost more money than CPU cycles on the client).
  Each document has an embedded link to the XSL file, like so:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="CCD.xsl"?>
```

If I just open the XML document using Chrome from the Mac terminal, like this:

```
sudo /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --allow-file-access-from-files [file].xml
```

...Chrome is smart enough to see the XSL reference and use its native XSLT processor to produce the HTML eventually used to display the document.
  Can I get the same behavior to happen using Angular, or must I use Angular's components to display the data?

It seems like Angular is heavily biased toward using Typescript to build components, and I see a lot of solutions out there that parse the XML into JSON, then build Angular components based on the JSON. But if Chrome already knows how to transform XML documents, and I have an XSL file with everything necessary, then transforming to JSON seems like a lot of extra processing. I feel like there might be a way to just let Chrome itself handle the XSLT processing.

Comment: I don't know Angular but your question's title asks about invoking "Chrome's built-in XML parser" while your text seems more about using Chrome's built-in XSLT processor. If you want Chrome to apply the XSLT referenced in an `xml-stylesheet` pi of an XML document then you need to load that XML document directly into a window or frame/iframe. If you want to do it with script then Chrome implements `XSLTProcessor` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XSLTProcessor) for Javascript and that way probably Typescript as well. Just for loading/parsing XML there is `XMLHttpRequest`.

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to document the answer that I eventually settled on, but first, a bit of clarification.

I was assuming that we were using Angular Universal, which uses Angular at both the server and client level. But that was wrong: we were using plain ol Angular, which is designed to spit out .html and .js files, to be used by browsers all across the land, where almost everything is done client-side except for parts of API requests. So my reference to 'maximize the work on the client side' misunderstood the use case: ALL work was already being done client-side.

I never did find a way to get Chrome to open an XML file and apply an XSLT transform by just handing it to Chrome in a tricky way, but given that the browser was doing all the work no matter how I approached it, I went with Martin Honnen's suggestion to use xsltProcessor.

[This link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XSLT/XSLT_JS_interface_in_Gecko/Basic_Example) shows a basic way to use xlstProcessor, and I didn't deviate far from this at all.

```
// initialize stuff
    const xsltProcessor = new XSLTProcessor();
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const xmlRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Get XSL stylesheet
    xmlRequest.open('GET', 'assets/CCD.xsl', false);
    xmlRequest.send(null);
    const xsltDocument = xmlRequest.responseXML;

    // Parse core string retrieved from the server to formal XML document
    const xmlDocument = parser.parseFromString(this.source, 'text/xml');

    // Load stylesheet, transform to html
    xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsltDocument);
    const html = xsltProcessor.transformToDocument(xmlDocument);
```